# VBA code to open password protected excel worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a master workbook that is linked to several other workbooks.

Two of the feeder workbooks are password protected and I am trying to get some VBA code that will allow the mater spreadsheet to automatically input these passwords.

So far I have:

```
Sub Password()

Workbooks.Open Filename:="S:\Folder\Sub Folder\File.xlsm", Password:="xyz", writerespassword:="xyz"

End Sub
```

However every time I open the master workbook I am still asked for the passwords.

Any help/advice for this newbie would be hugely welcome!!

Comment: If your Excel is set to update links automatically, that will happen before any of your code runs.

Comment: Excel does update automatically - does this mean that the code wont work?

Comment: The code will work, but too late. You'd have to disable the automatic updating of external links.

Comment: disabled updating of external links and still doesn't work :(

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean **specifically**?

Comment: I have disabled automatic updates and saved the settings. Then when I open my master spreadsheet it still asks for the passwords

Comment: What settings did you actually change and where?

Comment: I have a feeling this is where I show how inept I am with excel - File>Options>Formulas>Calc Options - change to manual

Comment: You need the Advanced section, scroll down near the bottom to the options for 'Update links to other documents' and 'Ask to update automatic links'.

Comment: Appreciate ALL your help here Rory, I have de-selected the 'update automatic links', saved the spreadsheet, closed and re-opened the mater spreadsheet and that option has been selected once again. Any suggestions? Sorry for the questions.

Comment: If you have the 'Ask to update automatic links' option checked, you should be prompted when any workbook opens as to whether you want to update any external links. The 'Update links to other documents' setting is workbook specific. You can also control it using the Edit links button on the Data tab, by choosing the Startup prompt button and then specifying the behaviour you want - presumablyl one of the don't update ones in your case.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your support ( I think I have solved it now) Not working seamlessly - but good enough for me (after weeks of trying) - think I will leave VBA and macros to those who get them!!!